# In Scala is it possible to pass a method as a parameter to a function

Tags: scala, methods

I want to do something like this:

```
(xs: Vector[Int], method:(Vector[Int] => Int)) = 
    selector match {
        case Case1 => (<compute xs>, <the max method of Vector>)
        case Case2 => (<compute xs>, <the min method of Vector>)
    }
 xs.method
```

It works to do this:

```
(xs: Vector[Int], fn:(Vector[Int] => Int)) = 
    selector match {
        case Case1 => (<compute xs>, (xs: Vector[Int]) => xs.max)
        case Case2 => (<compute xs>, (xs: Vector[Int]) => xs.min)
    }
 fn(xs)
```

Is there a way to say something like this more directly at the method level?

Thanks.

Comment: To make it clearer: so what you ask about is a reference to a method?

Comment: Yes, exactly -- along with a way to declare a parameter that can accept such a reference as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to create a lambda which simply calls the method you want on an input vector. You don't have to change anything in the function you'll use it in. I.e.:

```
def foo(vec: Vector[Int], f: Vector[Int] => Int) = {
  ???
  f(vec)
}

// using it:
foo( vec, _.max )
foo( vec, _.min )
```

FYI `_.max` is a sugar for `(x) => x.max`.

Comment: That's essentially what I did with the anonymous function. Perhaps there's just no notation for what might be called an anonymous method.